# asp.NET sending mail not by localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-1.1

I have problem with code of contact form for server using asp.NET 1.1, unfortunately upgrade of .NET is not possible. This code worked perfectly up to today. There was some change with the server and I have no idea what happened. My only guess is that I don't have permission for localhost anymore. Is there a possibility to change the way how it is sent on .NET 1.1? I tried by using gmail account, but I only got errors because of SSL and ports.

My code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
<script runat="server">    
    void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
        objEmail.To = "my_mail@gmail.com";
        objEmail.From = txtFrom.Text;
        objEmail.Cc = txtCc.Text;
        objEmail.Subject = "Contact";
        objEmail.Body = "Message: " + txtComments.Text + " <br> " + "name:" + txtName.Text;
        objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        objEmail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

        // Make sure you have appropriate replying permissions from your local system
                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";

        try{
            SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
                        }
        catch (Exception exc){
                        }
    }
</script>
```

After removing try/catch method:

Source error:

```
Line 16:        // Make sure you have appropriate replying permissions from your local system
Line 17:                 SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
Line 18: SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
Line 19:        
Line 20:     }
```

Stack trace:

```
[COMException (0x80040213): Nie powiodlo sie polaczenie warstwy transportu z serwerem.
]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters) +0
   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters) +473
   System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +58

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not access 'CDO.Message' object.]
   System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +113
   System.Web.Mail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) +1569
   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) +150
   ASP.div_aspx.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\helm\www2\wspolnicy.com\wwwroot\div.aspx:18
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +57
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +1273
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting any, mail is not sent.

Comment: If you're trying to send to Gmail or Hotmail, or most other mail providers for that matter, you'll need to use a "more official" SMTP server as unknown email senders are often equated with spam.

Comment: Your not getting an error because your wrapping the Send() method in a try/catch but not handling the exception.

Comment: I have put responce.redirect in exception and every time this exception is executing.

Comment: Remove the try/catch and see what the YSOD says.

Comment: YSOD is too long for comment, I will add it in main post.